# Display reCaptcha V3 only in login component in Angular

Tags: angular, recaptcha-v3

I have an **Angular** app.
I am trying to add **reCaptcha V3** in my login page.

**All is working but the recaptcha badge is showing in all pages of my application. I only need to display the recaptcha badgein login page.**

I included the script in my **index.html**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=MYSITEKEY"></script>
```

My **login.component.ts**

```
declare var grecaptcha: any;

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
private REC_SITEKEY= environment.REC_SITEKEY;
ngOnInit() {

  grecaptcha.ready(() => {
    grecaptcha.execute(this.REC_SITEKEY, { action: 'validate_captcha' }).then((token) => {
      this.rec_response=token;
    });
  });
  }
  }
```

I know I call the script in **index.html**. So the badge is showing in all page. But I try to include the script in **login.component.html**. But it is not working.

**So I need to hide the badge from all pages except in login component.**
How can I do that?

Comment: Dynamically add the script from the login component by modifying the dom. Or consider using 3rd party lib, such as `ngx-captcha`

Comment: I tried to load script dynamically, but got the error `ERROR ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and found this solution:
[https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/issues/153#:~:text=Based%20on%20%40psenechal,badge%20%7B%0A%09visibility%3A%20visible%3B%0A%7D](https://github.com/DethAriel/ng-recaptcha/issues/153#:%7E:text=Based%20on%20%40psenechal,badge%20%7B%0A%09visibility%3A%20visible%3B%0A%7D)

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
...

export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    constructor(
        ...
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        private recaptchaV3Service: ReCaptchaV3Service,
        ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'recaptcha');
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'recaptcha');
    }

}
CSS:

/* hide recaptcha badge*/
.grecaptcha-badge {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* only show recaptcha badge on needed pages */
body.recaptcha .grecaptcha-badge {
    visibility: visible;
}
```